# Cloud performance vs Desktop

Tags: performance, opencv, azure, visual-studio-2013

I have developed an app to analyze videos using OpenCV and Visual Studio 2013.  I was planning to run this app in the Azure assuming that it will run faster in cloud.  However, to my surprise, the app ran slower than my desktop, taking about twice the time when I configured the Azure instance with 8 cores.  It is a 64-bit app, compiled with appropriate compiler optimization.  Can someone help me understand why am I losing time in the cloud, and is there a way to improve the timing there?

The app takes as input a video (locally in each case) and outputs a flat file with the analysis data.

I am not sure why people are voting to close this question.  This is very much about programming and if possible, please help me in pinpointing the problem.

Comment: How much faster/slower is the disk? Have you separated out IO and CPU time? Do the core types/performance match what you have at home? Is your code using all the cores?

Comment: I am not sure about the disk.  Unfortunately, I do not know how to separate IO and CPU time in Windows applications.  The Azure machine had a lot more memory (56GB) vs my home machine (16GB); however, I donot have any control over what processor is given in Azure.  The code is using all the cores because when I ran on Azure with a single core, it took a lot longer (> 8 times my desktop).

Comment: I'd suggest breaking out the CPU and IO measurements. If it were my app, I'd just wrap the IO-specific and CPU-specific code with timers, and sum their respective values. And you'll be able to find information about what type of cores you're given in Azure, I have to believe.

Comment: CPU and IO are pretty intertwined.  The main loop in the code read a frame from the video, performs a lot of processing, and writes the result into a flat file.  The result is typically less than 512 bytes and is adequately buffered but I believe the frames are read in a non-buffered mode.

Comment: without information about single thread performance of your server and actual time given to you and information about your machine it is pretty useless question. Your processor characteristic is "8 cores". Thats not really a speed characteristic. Are you using a dedicated server? Cause if this is some cloud hosting with shared CPUs often you dont get as much as single reasonable desktop CPU time alotted there. Start by evaluating your Desktop and Azure machines by running some program or code which will provide CPU speed characteristic. When you see this ratio, a lot will become more clear.

Comment: Thanks Valentin.  My server is just my laptop, a Dell XPS.  So, it is dedicated to just this task.  I'll try to benchmark the CPU characteristics as suggested by you.  This sure helps.

Answer (score 3):

There is only going to be 3 reasons for this

1. Disk IO speed
2. CPU Speed
3. Memory Speed

Taking a look here you can see someone who actually checked the performance of on premise to cloud: [Azure compute power: Extra Large VM slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221167/azure-compute-power-extra-large-vm-slow)

Basically the Ghz is most likely slower (around 1.6) and disk IO speed, while local, is normally capped at 300 or 500 IOPS, which is only just higher than 15k rpm drives and no where near SSD level.

I am not sure on memory speed. While you can keep adding cores, most programs, even ones optimized for multiple cores, have a lot of dependencies on single threads, hence slowing the whole operation down. Increased Ghz is what can make a large difference.

Comment: I'd bet 9:1 that its CPU speed.